# Sql Pivot: Display fields vertically

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I am trying to create a query where basically the the data displays horizontally as opposed to vertically. I believe its referred to as pivoting (I'm kind of new to this). Consider the following:
I can query a students addresses and they would display like such

```
ID    Email
27    jd@yahoo.com
27    johndoe47@gmail.com
27    MrDoe@hotmail.com
```

I would rather the data be displayed horizontally such as

```
ID  Email1          Email2               Email3
27  jd@yahoo.com    johndoe47@gmail.com  MrDoe@hotmail.com
```

I have accomplished this with the query below for one person.

```
SELECT Id,
MAX(CASE WHEN rownum =1 THEN B.EMAIL_ADDRESS END) AS "Email1",
MAX(CASE WHEN rownum =2 THEN B.EMAIL_ADDRESS END) AS "Email2",
MAX(CASE WHEN rownum =3 THEN B.EMAIL_ADDRESS END) AS "Email3",
MAX(CASE WHEN rownum =4 THEN B.EMAIL_ADDRESS END) AS "Email4"
FROM MyTable B
where B.Id in (21538) 
group by B.Id
```

This works for one person and mainly because I'm using rownum. Value under column Entry4 would be null in this example. I know I'm close but I'm not sure how to get it to work for multiple students and to stop from using rownum.
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want three, you can use conditional aggregation

```
select id,
       max(case whens seqnum = 1 then email end) as email1,
       max(case whens seqnum = 2 then email end) as email2,
       max(case whens seqnum = 3 then email end) as email3
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by email) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id;
```

Comment: Greetings, I think this does work best. It does give the emails in a vertical manner. I've been trying manipulate the query though to include the email type as well. Each email address has an email type. So it would be something like

Comment: @user1898629 . . . Just add additional columns with `max()` using the `type` instead of `email`.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this issue. I was able to produce what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about **columns** (as such a thing doesn't scale), consider `listagg` which lets you "concatenate" up to 4000 characters of e-mail addresses.

For example (note that lines #1 - 10 represent sample data; you already have that in your table so query you might want to consider begins at line #11):

```
SQL> with test (id, email) as
  2    (select 27, 'jd@yahoo.com'        from dual union all
  3     select 27, 'johndoe47@gmail.com' from dual union all
  4     select 27, 'MrDoe@hotmail.com'   from dual union all
  5     --
  6     select 25, 'little@hotmail.com'  from dual union all
  7     select 25, 'foot@gmail.com'      from dual union all
  8     --
  9     select 13, 'bigfoot@net.hr'      from dual
 10    )
 11  select id,
 12    listagg(email, ', ') within group (order by email) email
 13  from test
 14  group by id
 15  order by id;

        ID EMAIL
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        13 bigfoot@net.hr
        25 foot@gmail.com, little@hotmail.com
        27 MrDoe@hotmail.com, jd@yahoo.com, johndoe47@gmail.com

SQL>
```

Or, a little bit prettier (with `rpad`):

```
<snip>
 11  select id,
 12    listagg(rpad(email, 20, ' '), ' | ') within group (order by email) email
 13  from test
 14  group by id
 15  order by id;

        ID EMAIL
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
        13 bigfoot@net.hr
        25 foot@gmail.com       | little@hotmail.com
        27 MrDoe@hotmail.com    | jd@yahoo.com         | johndoe47@gmail.com

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your email categories (Email1, Email2 etc), and then use them in a PIVOT clause. Make sure you code enough categories into the PIVOT, though. (Eg when using the following query: if someone has 5 email addresses, one of their addresses will not be in the result set.)

```
select *
from (
  select id, email
  , 'Email' || row_number() over ( partition by id order by email ) emailcategory_
  from emailaddresses
)
pivot (
  max( email ) for ( emailcategory_ ) in (
    'Email1' as "Email1"  -- optional: use AS ... here to "beautify" the column headings
  , 'Email2' as "Email2"
  , 'Email3'
  , 'Email4' 
  )
) ;
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e89b4628fd4114401d9b085db7554e24).